# Angular custom filter works but the code is throwing errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have the following filter which looks at two times, subtracts one from the other and if the figure is greater than 0 the filter passes

Here is the code

```
delayControllers.filter('customDelayFilter', function() {
  return function(data) {
    return data.filter(value => (new Date(value.etd) - new Date(value.std)) > 0);
  };
});
```

in google console errors are thrown

**Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined**

in phpstorm the => shows an error as does the > symbol (expression expected)

Now here is the rub, this code works exactly as expected when run. I call it using

```
 <tr ng-repeat="service in listOfServices | customDelayFilter">
```

I am only getting results where the row etd - std is greater than 0.. on ever device EXCEPT IOS. When i remove this filter the page works fine on IOS, so looks like Safari on IOS is being picky with the error

Is there a neater way to rewrite the above filter which was kindly supplied in a thread I raised some weeks ago (now closed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter expect a defined array. I suspect that `listOfServices` may be not yet initialised when the `ng-repeat` runs for the first time, depending how you initialise it.

Either, ensure `listOfServices` is initialised, or add a check in the filter, i.e.

```
delayControllers.filter('customDelayFilter', function() {
   return function(data) {
      if (data) {
         return data.filter(value => (new Date(value.etd) - new Date(value.std)) > 0);
      }
      else {
         return [];
      }
  };
});
```

Comment: It should have pccured to me I was pulling the data asynchronously and the filter was operating on data that just wasnt there. I did try an ng-init="listOfServices=[]" but taht didnt work so I thought it was something else. Your solution worked perfectly. Thanks